# Is public data available for routes that enter/exit a certain airspace?

Tags: air-traffic-control, usa, flight-path

I'm interested in air traffic density and [flux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flux) (i.e., traffic that enters and exits) for the ZLA airspace. A good first pass would be flights that begin or end in ZLA (and that data is pretty easy to get from somewhere like OpenFlights, but that doesn't include routes like PHX-SEA, where a flight would pass through ZLA on its way from ZAB to ZSE. Is there any public information available about what routes *pass through* ZLA?

(Actually, I'm much more interested in the air traffic density and flux specifically for the Los Angeles metropolitan area, but I figure starting at the area control center level might be a good place to start.)

Comment: Related http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/12375/6886. You may find the answers there helpful.

Comment: @digitgopher they definitely were! It got me started but ultimately did not address my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A free public resource would be the [FAA's statistics page](https://www.faa.gov/data_research/). I'm not sure if they have the specifics you need but they have a lot of data available. It would probably be easier to find data specific to the airports than it would for the whole artcc. Flight data doesn't usually include what airspace they pass through but where they depart and arrive.

There are commercial sites that have the raw data. FlightAware has full xml data for pretty much all scheduled flights going back several years. It's a treasure trove of data, it's a matter of extracting it. If you can write an api then  have options for using their data for a per-query fee. Their info page is [here](https://flightaware.com/commercial/flight) Their prices are in fractions of a penny, but I really know nothing about api's so I have no idea how quickly they would add up. It probably depends on how efficient the api is in getting the information with the least number of queries.